# How to fetch objects, and create new objects if they do not exist?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How can I update my database rows and create new rows if they do not exist with the operations defined in my DB context? I am using the unit of work pattern in my code [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#implement-a-generic-repository-and-a-unit-of-work-class)

I am using the `DefaultIfEmpty()` method to create new objects if they do not exist in the database.

```
// this code runs every 10 sec
foreach(/* possible values for property in contract entity */)
{

      var contract = unitOfWork.OptionsContractRepository
.Get(/* loop variable match */)
.DefaultIfEmpty(new OptionsContract { /* set default property values */}).Single();

// contract has a list of 'marks'
      var mark = contract.OptionsMarks.Where(/* property filter */).DefaultIfEmpty(new OptionsMark { /* set default property values */}).Single();

      // update some properties in 'mark'...

      mark.OptionsContract = contract; // set 'contract' for the 'mark'

      unitOfWork.OptionsContractRepository.Insert(contract);
}
unitOfWork.Save();
```

I want the code to not worry about whether the object exists in the database and just create new ones on the fly. I am getting errors when I try to save everything to the database:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'UlyssesPriceModel2.OptionsContract' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.'

How can I do this with the unit of work pattern?

Comment: What would happen if you add an object with the same key but other data is different? Of course EF doesn't check the rest of the object, and it shouldn't. So this check is required to retain data integrity.

Comment: But I'm not setting keys anywhere. I am simply creating new objects and using the repository's insert method. I thought the unit of work pattern allows you to insert multiple objects or make changes and then commit everything at once.

Comment: Look at the link.  Adding you should be using the Insert code which has following :  dbSet.Add(entity);  So you need to pass a new entity.

Comment: Ok, so that means Add will try to insert the object again. i think that's why it's failing. i forgot to mention in my question that the for loop runs every 10 seconds

Comment: So do you recommend I check the state of the entity using DbEntityEntry.State before calling Insert() ? If the state is 'Detached' then call insert() and if it is 'Added' then call Update()